# Click function applying to all elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, click, this

I have 2 sets of tabs on my page that share the same classes.  I need my click function to only apply to the tab-menu thats clicked, but instead it applies to both.  I know the answer lies in using "this" but I can't figure out how to plug it in

**HTML:**

```
<div className="tabbed-menu" id="tabs">
<ul className="tab-list">
<li data-tab-item="1" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Active Section</a></li>
<li data-tab-item="2" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Two</a></li>
<li data-tab-item="3" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Three</a></li>
 </ul>
<div className="tab-container">
<div data-tab-item="1" id="tab1" className="tab-content"><p>Content Goes Here</p></div>
<div data-tab-item="2" id="tab2" className="tab-content"><p>Second Content Goes Here</p></div>
<div data-tab-item="3" id="tab3" className="tab-content"><p>Third Content Goes Here</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div className="tabbed-menu" id="tabs2">
<ul className="tab-list">
<li data-tab-item="1" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Active Section</a></li>
<li data-tab-item="2" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Two</a></li>
<li data-tab-item="3" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Three</a></li>
 </ul>
<div className="tab-container">
<div data-tab-item="1" id="tab1" className="tab-content"><p>Content Goes Here</p></div>
<div data-tab-item="2" id="tab2" className="tab-content"><p>Second Content Goes Here</p></div>
<div data-tab-item="3" id="tab3" className="tab-content"><p>Third Content Goes Here</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if (!$('[data-tab-item]').hasClass('active').length){
        $('li[data-tab-item]').first().addClass('active');
        $('div[data-tab-item]').first().addClass('active');
    }   
    $(".tab-item").click(function(){
        var tabNumber = $(this).attr('data-tab-item');
        $('[data-tab-item]').removeClass('active');
        $('[data-tab-item='+ tabNumber +']').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: are you using react? `className` might imply this

Comment: yep I'm using react jsx ^^

Comment: tbh you should use react for this logic and try to avoid jquery.

Comment: I know and I wish I could -  I built a react page but our client is still using jquery components.  eventually we'll get everything into react but its a bit of a mess right now...

Answer (score 1):

The callback function you pass to the click method can also receive a parameter in witch the event data is passed. The event data has a property called target. witch is the node on witch the event has been emitted. 
 For your case you should not do this:
    $(this)
 but instead something like:

```
$(".tab-item").click(function(event){
  var tabNumber = $(event.target).attr('data-tab-item');
  $('[data-tab-item]').removeClass('active');
  $('[data-tab-item='+ tabNumber +']').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: sorry, but despite the given event param, this will still target any item with the `data-tab-` attribute

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` will search for the closest parent. From there on you can find any element within that element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$('[data-tab-item]').hasClass('active').length) {
    $('li[data-tab-item]').first().addClass('active');
    $('div[data-tab-item]').first().addClass('active');
  }
  $(".tab-item").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $menu = $this.closest('.tabbed-menu');
    $menu.find('[data-tab-item]').removeClass('active');
    var tabNumber = $this.attr('data-tab-item');
    $menu.find('[data-tab-item=' + tabNumber + ']').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
I have 2 sets of tabs on my page that share the same classes. I need my click function to only apply to the tab-menu thats clicked, but instead it applies to both. I know the answer lies in using "this" but I can't figure out how to plug it in HTML:

<div class="tabbed-menu" id="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-list">
    <li data-tab-item="1" class="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Active Section</a></li>
    <li data-tab-item="2" class="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Two</a></li>
    <li data-tab-item="3" class="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-container">
    <div data-tab-item="1" id="tab1" class="tab-content">
      <p>Content Goes Here</p>
    </div>
    <div data-tab-item="2" id="tab2" class="tab-content">
      <p>Second Content Goes Here</p>
    </div>
    <div data-tab-item="3" id="tab3" class="tab-content">
      <p>Third Content Goes Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabbed-menu" id="tabs2">
  <ul class="tab-list">
    <li data-tab-item="1" class="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Active Section</a></li>
    <li data-tab-item="2" class="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Two</a></li>
    <li data-tab-item="3" class="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-container">
    <div data-tab-item="1" id="tab1" class="tab-content">
      <p>Content Goes Here</p>
    </div>
    <div data-tab-item="2" id="tab2" class="tab-content">
      <p>Second Content Goes Here</p>
    </div>
    <div data-tab-item="3" id="tab3" class="tab-content">
      <p>Third Content Goes Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3390251 glad I could help. but like I mentioned already: it might be smarter to avoid jquery and use react for this kind of logic.

Comment: I wish I could and I agree :) .  I built a react page but our client is still using jquery components so its a bit of a mess right now.  the plan is to move all the components to react.. eventually.

Comment: after some further testing, this isn't doing the trick.   it worked when if I put it in a script tag in my index.html file, but, I need to use in componentDidMount on my js file.   it throws an error saying $this and $menu are undefined (no-undef)...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `>` selector which selects the child of the selected element.  `parent>child`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!$('#tabs>.tabb1>[data-tab-item]').hasClass('active').length){
    alert("s");
        $('#tabs>.tabb1>li[data-tab-item]').first().addClass('active');
        $('#tabs>.tabb1>div[data-tab-item]').first().addClass('active');
    }   
    $("#tabs2>.tabb2>.tab-item").click(function(){
        var tabNumber = $(this).attr('data-tab-item');
        $('#tabs2>.tabb2>[data-tab-item]').removeClass('active');
        $('#tabs2>.tabb2>[data-tab-item='+ tabNumber +']').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div className="tabbed-menu" id="tabs">
<ul className="tab-list">
<li data-tab-item="1" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Active Section</a></li>
<li data-tab-item="2" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Two</a></li>
<li data-tab-item="3" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Three</a></li>
 </ul>
<div className="tab-container">
<div data-tab-item="1" id="tab1" className="tab-content"><p>Content Goes Here</p></div>
<div data-tab-item="2" id="tab2" className="tab-content"><p>Second Content Goes Here</p></div>
<div data-tab-item="3" id="tab3" className="tab-content"><p>Third Content Goes Here</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<div className="tabbed-menu" id="tabs2">
<ul className="tab-list">
<li data-tab-item="1" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Active Section</a></li>
<li data-tab-item="2" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Two</a></li>
<li data-tab-item="3" className="tab-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item Three</a></li>
 </ul>
<div className="tab-container">
<div data-tab-item="1" id="tab1" className="tab-content"><p>Content Goes Here</p></div>
<div data-tab-item="2" id="tab2" className="tab-content"><p>Second Content Goes Here</p></div>
<div data-tab-item="3" id="tab3" className="tab-content"><p>Third Content Goes Here</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```